# AWS VPC vs Subnet for Application Wrapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to get a better understanding of AWS organization patterns.

Suppose I define the term "application stack" as a set of interconnected AWS resources (e.g. a java microservice behind ELB + dynamoDB for peristence), then I need some way of isolating independent stacks.  Each application would get a separate dynamodb or kinesis so there is no need for cross-stack resource sharing.  But the microservices do need to communicate with each other.

A-priori I could see either of the two organizational methods being used:

1. Create a VPC for each independent stack (1 VPC per 1 Application)
2. Create a single "production" VPC and each stack resides within a separate private subnet.

There could be up to 100s of these independent "stacks" within the organization so there's the potential for resource exhaustion if there is a hard limit on VPC count.  But other than resources scarcity, **what are the decision criteria around creating a new VPC or using a pre-existing VPC for each stack?**  Are there strong positive or negative consequences to either approach?

Thank you in advance for consideration and response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subnet's and IP addresses are a limited commodity within your VPC. The number of IP addresses cannot be increased within your VPC if you hit that limit. Also, by default, all subnets can talk to other subnets, so there may be security concerns. Any limits on the number of VPCs are a soft limit and can be increased by AWS support.

For these reasons, separate distinct projects at the VPC level. Never mix projects within a VPC. That's just asking for trouble.

Also, if your production projects are going to include non-VPC-applicable resources, such as IAM users, DynamoDB tables, SQS queues, etc., then I also recommend isolating those projects within their own AWS account (at the production level).

This way, you're not looking at a list of DynamoDB tables that includes tables from different projects.